# how to link exist design to exsiting laravel project

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

how to link exist design to existing laravel project
the designer in my team give me a folder which include (css-folder , js-folder , fonts-folder ) and a lot of pages that have .html extension

how could I modify my Laravel project to render the design files 
the steps that I already make it

Comment: Hello, first change .html to .blade.php.
Then move css and javascript code to assets folder.

Comment: yeah I already did that … whats next

Comment: Maybe you must create a new model.
Can i see the your file structure (existing files+new files)?